# AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'split' in python

Tags: python, split, attributes, timestamp, attributeerror

```
#Create the independent data set
for day in df_days:
    days.append([int(day.split('-')[4])])
#Create the dependent data set (adj close prices)
for adj_close_price in df_adj_close:
    adj_close_prices.append( float(adj_close_price))
```

I get the wrong message #"AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'split'"

Could someone please help?

Comment: `day` is a `Timestamp` object, and it has no attribute `split`. If you want get help, you should tell us from which package you import the `Timestamp`.

Comment: I import from a stock price, I downloaded the data to my computer first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a string object to perform the slip operation. i believe u are using time stamp ("datetime" type) object. use the string format for object or use "day = datetimeobj.strftime("%d")" directly on timestamp object if you are using "datetime". if you are using a timestamp first convert it to "datetime", "datetimeobj=datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)"

Comment: Hi, Could you please specific to a code? Thanks.